# Do not understand JavaScript sort function?

Tags: javascript

I do not understand the order the array elements are passed to the functions.
I know it takes two parameters a and b, if the first time it compares 3 and 20, what does it compare the next time?

```
   console.log(["a", "b", "c"].sort());
   console.log([3, 20,10000].sort(function(a,b){
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;

     } else if (a ==b) {
        return  0;

     } else {
        return  1;
     }

   }));
  }());
```

Comment: [Here you go](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 1):

The sort process passes the comparator function (the function you pass in with two parameters) pairs of values from the array. You don't know, and you don't have to know, which values they are; all your function must do is return consistent comparison results. Your function may get the same pair of values more than once, and it may get them in a different order.

The sort in modern JavaScript runtimes is *probably* a quicksort implementation, but the precise details are not specified; all it has to do is successfully sort the array.

Comment: Thank you, I love learning something new, but people are so quick to down vote a question. Its like everyone on here were born programmers.